# How switch between tabs in Output View in Nebeans with keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: netbeans, ide

In Output View in Netbeans I have several tabs such as:

- Java DB Database Proccess
- GlassFish
- Application (debug)
- Debugger Console
- etc.

I would like to switch between them using keyboard only. How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will allow you to cycle through all panes available for your open projects, at least in Netbeans v7.3.1. You can also use the arrow keys to navigate while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> will shift focus directly to the output pane.

Check out [this](http://netbeanside61.blogspot.com/2008/04/top-10-netbeans-ide-keyboard-shortcuts.html) and [this](https://netbeans.org/project_downloads/usersguide/shortcuts-73.pdf) for more details and shortcuts.